# MvcCheckBoxList, RadioButtons e Inputs de texto

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, visual-studio-2013

Estou com um projeto onde estou usando o MvcCheckBoxList.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

- Teria como eu colocar um mvccheckboxlist junto com rádio buttons e inputs ? Pois estou em um projeto em uma escola que tenho que gravar algumas ocorrências e eu preciso que nessas ocorrências, ao marcar um check box, apareça um input, mas só em alguns. Explicando melhor, seria os radio buttons para o tipo de ocorrência(Advertência ou Suspensão) e o mvccheckboxlist para as causas(bagunça, xingamento, etc) e ao escolher algumas causas aparecer um input de texto pra complementar. Ou seja, relacionar o rádio button ao check box. E depois disso eu recuperar, editar, deletar e adicionar outras ocorrências. Lembrando aqui que eu já usei o mvccheckboxlist, mas não sei como gravar os valores deles no banco, e eu já até tenho o model de Aluno, que faz o cadastro dos alunos. No caso da ocorrência eu teria que criar outra tabela ?

Enfim, vou postar o código html aqui, pra que vocês tenham uma ideia de como que eu queria que ficasse:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#ocorrencias">
            Ocorrências do Aluno
        </a>
     </h4>
  </div>

  <div id="ocorrencias" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="radio-inline">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" value="Advertencia" id="Advertencia" />
                Advertência
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" value="Suspensao" id="Suspensao" />
                Suspensão por: <input type="text" class="col-xs-1" name="dias" id="dias"/> dias.
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="atividade" id="atividade" value="" checked>
                Estar deixando de fazer as atividades discentes ou não ter concluido a mesma
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="material" id="material" value="">
                Não trazer o material necessario para as aulas do dia
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="uniforme" id="uniforme" value="">
                Não estar devidamente uniformizado
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="conversa" id="conversa" value="">
                Estar conversando excessivamente em sala de aula
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="atrapalhando" id="atrapalhando" value="">
                Estar brincando e atrapalhando os colegarr em sala de aula
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="atividadesDocentes" id="atividadesDocentes" value="">
                Estar impedindo as atividades docentes
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="brincando" id="brincando" value="">
                Estar com brincadeira de mau gosto na escola <input type="text" name="motivo" id="motivo"/>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="aula" id="aula" value="">
                Estar frequentemente "matando aula" ou chegando atrasado
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="fugindo" id="fugindo" value="">
                Ter saído da escola sem autorização, fugiu ás <input type="text" name="hora" id="hora"/>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="foraDeSala" id="foraDeSala" value="">
                Estar fora da sala de aulas <input type="text" name="fora" id="fora"/>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="agredido" id="agredido" value="">
                Ter agredido, faltado com o devido respeito aos colegas <input type="text" name="respeito" id="respeito" />
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="respeito" id="respeito" value="">
                Ter faltado com respeito ao professor
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="equipamentos" id="equipamentos" value="">
                Estar usando equipamentos eletro-eletrônicos em sala de aula <input type="text" name="equipamentos" id="equipamentos" />
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="outros" id="outros" value="">
                Outros <textarea name="outros" id="outros"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>

     </div>
  </div>
```

Caso precisem de mais informação, eu posto aqui, model ou controller pra que fique mais claro.

Comment: Você somente quer mostrar os text? Cada text está vinculado a uma propriedade no model?

Comment: O que acontece é que eu nem criei o model de ocorrências ainda, porque num sei como relacionar esse model de ocorrências com o model de aluno. E queria, gravar, editar, listar e remover essas ocorrências sem que os dados do aluno sejam afetados !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz alguns ajustes em nomes de input, radio e checkbox que não tinha e estavam errados ou repetidos

**HTML**

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.BaseModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Listas";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Listas</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#ocorrencias">
                        Ocorrências do Aluno
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.CheckBoxListFor(
        p => p.BaseSend.Send,
        p => p.BaseAll,
        p => p.Id,
        p => p.Name,
        b => b.BaseSelected
    )
            </div>

            <div id="ocorrencias" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="radio-inline">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" value="true" id="advertencia" name="advertencia" />
                            Advertência
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" value="true" id="suspensao" name="suspensao" />
                            Suspensão por: <input type="text" class="col-xs-1" name="dias" id="dias" /> dias.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="atividade" id="atividade" value="true">
                            Estar deixando de fazer as atividades discentes ou não ter concluido a mesma
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="material" id="material" value="true">
                            Não trazer o material necessario para as aulas do dia
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="uniforme" id="uniforme" value="true">
                            Não estar devidamente uniformizado
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="conversa" id="conversa" value="true">
                            Estar conversando excessivamente em sala de aula
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="atrapalhando" id="atrapalhando" value="true">
                            Estar brincando e atrapalhando os colegarr em sala de aula
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="atividadesDocentes" id="atividadesDocentes" value="true">
                            Estar impedindo as atividades docentes
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="brincando" id="brincando" value="true">
                            Estar com brincadeira de mau gosto na escola <input type="text" name="tmotivo" id="tmotivo" />
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="aula" id="aula" value="true">
                            Estar frequentemente "matando aula" ou chegando atrasado
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="fugindo" id="fugindo" value="true">
                            Ter saído da escola sem autorização, fugiu ás <input type="text" name="thora" id="thora" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="foradesala" id="foradesala" value="true">
                            Estar fora da sala de aulas <input type="text" name="tfora" id="tfora" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="agredido" id="agredido" value="true">
                            Ter agredido, faltado com o devido respeito aos colegas <input type="text" name="trespeito" id="trespeito" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="respeito" id="respeito" value="true">
                            Ter faltado com respeito ao professor
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="equipamentos" id="equipamentos" value="true">
                            Estar usando equipamentos eletro-eletrônicos em sala de aula <input type="text" name="tequipamentos" id="tequipamentos" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="outros" id="outros" value="true">
                            Outros <textarea name="toutros" id="toutros"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-success" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

---

**ActionResult (Métodos)**

```
public ActionResult Listas()
{
    BaseModel baseModel = new BaseModel();

    baseModel.BaseAll = new List<Base>(){
        new Base() { Id = 1, Name="Produto 1", IsSelected = true, Tags="Produtos"},
        new Base()  {Id = 2, Name="Produto 2", IsSelected = false, Tags="Produtos"}
    };

    baseModel.BaseSelected = new List<Base>(){
         new Base() { Id = 1, Name="Produto 1", IsSelected = true, Tags="Produtos"},
    };

    return View(baseModel);
}
```

---

1 - Essa é uma das maneiras de recuperar, mas, eu não gosto muito de ficar trabalhando com [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) por causa dos erros e tratamentos que temos que fazer

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Listas(BaseSend BaseSend, FormCollection form)
{
    bool advertencia = false;
    bool suspensao = false;

    bool.TryParse(form.Get("advertencia"), out advertencia);
    bool.TryParse(form.Get("suspensao"), out suspensao);

    // e assim por diante quando for caixa de texto seria Int32 ou String

    int dias = 0;
    int.TryParse(form.Get("dias"), out dias);

    String trespeito = form.Get("trespeito");

    //são exemplos podem causar erros se não existir tá indice

    return RedirectToAction("Listas");
}
```

---

2 - Use essa forma, porque, os dados já teria um tipo, perceba que os checkbox todos tem *`value="true"`* isso é importante para ele recuperar um valor boleano e string para que ele carrega as caixas de texto, perceba também `dias` eu coloque `int`, se o dado colocado na caixa for número ele vai recuperar esse número para você ...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Listas(BaseSend BaseSend, 
    bool? advertencia, 
    bool? suspensao,
    bool? atividade,
    bool? material,
    bool? uniforme,
    bool? conversa,
    bool? atrapalhando,
    bool? atividadesdocentes,
    bool? brincando, 
    string tmotivo,
    int? dias,
    bool? aula,
    bool? fugindo,
    bool? foradesala,
    string tfora,
    bool? agredido,
    string trespeito,
    bool? respeito,
    bool? equipamentos,
    string tequipamentos,
    bool? outros,
    string toutros)
{
    if (advertencia.HasValue)
    {

    }
    // e assim vai comparando todo os campos
    return RedirectToAction("Listas");
}
```

Comment: Cara extremamente útil, muito bom mesmo ! Abriu minha mente ! Agora, como que eu faria pra relacionar essas ocorrências ao aluno, pra que fique gravado no banco junto com o aluno a ocorrência, além dos dados é claro, atrelar um ao outro. E dessa forma que está aqui, eu poderia listar, salvar, editar e remover se for o caso ?

Comment: Sim se vai ter que passar,a id do aluno num campo hidden

Comment: E controller das ocorrências vai ser desse modelo, ou vou ter que colocar tudo no mesmo controller? Já que vou ter criar um model só para as ocorrências.

Comment: Eu gosto de dividir a responsabilidade, na verdade eu uso POO no seu conceito mesmo, ou seja, faço cada um no seu controller, utilizo ajax para resolver gravação em outros controllers, etc. Existem aqueles que usam um controller para uma determinado problema / solução. mas, isso vai de programador para programador ou de solução para solução, apesar que você pode usar um classe de repositório para melhorar a solução. Tem várias formas mas, isso vai depender do seu entendimento. Dúvidas tamos ai!

Comment: Na verdade, também prefiro muito mais cada um no seu lugar. Pra num ficar uma bagunça de código. Quero que fique organizado, então prefiro fazer cada um no seu controller ! Então, como que eu usaria ajax pra resolver essa gravação ? Porque quero colocar as views de ocorrências na view de detalhes do aluno. Pra ficar uma coisa só. Como que eu poderia prosseguir ? @FCCDias quando puder vamos conversar no chat, pode ser ?

Comment: caso tenha um exemplo pra que eu possa me basear, seria ótimo !